# Can I create an array with numpy.random that has correlation to another numpy.random array already created

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am creating an array that randomly generates an infants birthweight.  I want to create a second array using numpy.random that randomly picks the infants disposition after 1 year.  The difficulty I am having is that I want correlation between the 2 arrays.  The lower the birthweight the higher the chance of death after 1 year (23%).

Any ideas???

```
#Setting Parameters for birthweight, low = 400g, High = 1500g

bw = np.random.randint(400, 1500, size=100) #this function draws random 
numbers from a uniform distribution
dip = np.random.choice(["Died", "At Home", "Still Hos", "Unknown"], 100, p= 
[0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6])
# Populating the Dataset

df = pd.DataFrame({ "Birthweight" : bw, "Disposition" : dip})
df
```

Comment: So do you want to choose the second array from a distribution related to the first array? That's one way to understand it.. The second way is to generate two random arrays and impart the correlation matrix onto the second array using a Cholesky decomposition, I think .

Comment: i think the most straight forward way to do it , is your first suggestion. The first array is birthweight.  How do I choose a second array called 'disposition' from a distribution related to 'birthweight' (the first array)......

Comment: Well, it's not really a coding question. If you know what probability mass function that disposition should be drawn from it's trivial in numpy. You just need to make your list of probabilities `[0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.6]` depend on birth weight in an appropriate way

Comment: According to what you said, as birth weight gets lower the 0.2 will increase to 0.43 and the other probabilities will decrease accordingly, for example

Comment: So is death probability linear in birth weight ? What is the relationship between the pmf and birth weight ? If you answer that question, you're set. But it's empirical statistics, not numpy

Comment: what you are saying makes sense but I cant figure how to write a code that will generate realistic stats.

Comment: so as birthweight increases, the chance of death decreases  but not completely as birthweight is not the only variable

Comment: You are trying to synthesize the joint distribution of two random variables -- birthweight (continuous) and disposition (discrete). There are many ways to get a particular correlation between these. For example, if you just set disposition to "Died" whenever birthweight is below 420, you will get a -0.23 correlation between birthweight and the 0/1 indicator that disposition=Died. But I doubt this is what you want. So you probably need to find a little more information about this joint distribution. For example, is birthweight really uniformly distributed, or should it be normal?